# How to create a new textfield in a panel at runtime with Java Swing and Netbeans UI

Tags: java, swing, button, netbeans, runtime

i have a problem: I want to create a new textfield at runtime by clicking a button (jButton1). But when i click the button nothing happens. Can anybody help?
I use Netbeans and create the existing window with the design manager from Netbeans automatically (new JFrame Form).
This is the code. I only added the code in the jButton1ActionPerformed-Method which will be processed when i click the button.

Thanks for help!

```
package test;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Test
     */
    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(519, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(163, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(73, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(171, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

        jPanel1.add(new JLabel("Test: "));
        jPanel1.add(textField);

        jPanel1.revalidate();
        jPanel1.repaint();

        pack();

    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I tried:

`jPanel1.revalidate(); jPanel1.repaint();`

But this also did not work.

Comment: @GrindingForReputation??? what in the world? How will that help? To the OP, the problem is your layout manager. The one that you're using will not readily accept addition of components in this way. The solution is to use a different one. Either that or use a CardLayout, or add the JTextField from the start, but make it not visible. Then later make it visible.

Comment: you see that the layout used by Netbeans seems to require a lot of additional work (creating groups, adding the components to that groups, adding gaps, ...) - apparently this is not being done for the text field, so it get not laid out by the layout manager. Maybe it is *easier* to add a component (JPanel) or the components (label, field) at the start, but having these not visible (yet) until needed. @GrindingForReputation `revalidate()` (already being called) also calls `validate()`!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels not really sure how that works either :> but it seemed to *somehow* work for me in a project I was working on (or it must have been the other way around) so I wouldn't say it **works** just **try**, also yes I was also about to recommend creating the JTextField and later making it visible

Comment: @GrindingForReputation: but how on earth can it help when the OP is using a GroupLayout? That is clearly the issue here. Best not to throw out suggestions that are obviously not going to help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sure :> Also I just searched everywhere on NetBeans, but using NetBeans IDE's JFrame Form automatically uses GroupLayout and it is not editable as to my knowledge.

Comment: @GrindingForReputation: when using NetBeans, GroupLayout is the *default* layout, but you are not forced to use it as NetBeans allows one to select any layout of choice, and in fact in this situation, the OP should select another layout, if only for a JPanel that holds the region where the JTextField will appear.

Comment: @GrindingForReputation *but using NetBeans IDE's JFrame Form automatically uses GroupLayout* - which is why we generally suggest that you don't use the IDE to generate the frame code. When you create the code manually you are in full control and the code is easier to maintain. If you ever change to a different IDE the code won't be maintainable by the IDE.